# Splitting number into 2 lists of numbers of certain range

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create 2 lists of numbers, generated randomly with certain range.
So, if user want to generate lists as above from value 1000 (example) it should split 1000 into 2 lists:

1st list - 4 numbers in range from 40 to 80

2nd list - 5 numbers in range from 80 to 160

Sum of all produced list numbers must equal input (or hardcoded number, doesn't matter). Main range of input 560 - 1120.

Python 3.7 actually, and some problems in declaring that

See code below, I've managed to generate random 2 lists of certain range but I don't have idea how to work that out that it can have declared sum and split it into lists rather than generating random lists all together.

```
import random

def function():
    num = 4
    start = 40
    end = 80

    def rand(start, end, num):
        res = []

        for j in range(num):
            res.append(random.randint(start,end))

        return res
    return rand(start, end, num)


def function2():
    num2 = 5
    start2 = 80
    end2 = 160
    def rand2(start2, end2, num2):
        res2 = []

        for k in range(num2):
            res2.append(random.randint(start2,end2))

        return res2
    return rand2(start2, end2, num2)

a = function()
b = function2()

print (a)
print (sum(a))

print(b)
print(sum(b))

suma = sum(a+b)
print (suma)
```

If anyone could help me solving that I'd be really glad, I'm making a little project and this is required :)